# how to get file path in java/android , (getPath , alternatives written methods method causes app to crash)

Tags: java, android, illegalargumentexception

Please would you show a trusted way to get file path , that works across APIs,

// sorry for the long question.

i am trying to make very simple app, it takes a video from the device and then compress it, for compression i use (fishwjy VideoCompressor )library ,as the class(VideoCompressingTask) from the library requires the path of the video and a destination path in its constructor, i try to pass the video path using (getPath() method it make the app crash with illegal argument exception, i then used a function from another question here on the site to get the path it does the same , i finally tried a function from the (Util) class from the library project on github (Util.getFilePath()), it works very fine with the lower APIs (23) ,but with the higher APIs (29,28) it crashes with the same exception, i tried to let it use (getPath()) at higher APIs  , use getAbsulotePath() instead it also crashes, what i am missing?? what i am doing wrong???, any help would be really appreciated, thanks in advance.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
 Uri videoUri;
 static final int GET_VIDEO_REQUEST=64;
 private String outputDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath();
 String videoUriPath;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getVideoFromPhone();




}


void getVideoFromPhone(){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("video/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(intent,GET_VIDEO_REQUEST);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==GET_VIDEO_REQUEST && resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        videoUri=data.getData();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Video added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        compressVideoForUpload();


    }
}

void compressVideoForUpload(){
    try{

        videoUriPath=Util.getFilePath(this,videoUri);
        String distinationDirectory=outputDir+File.separator+"out"+".mp4";


        VideoCompressTask task =VideoCompress.compressVideoLow(videoUri.getPath(), distinationDirectory, new VideoCompress.CompressListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Compression started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " video Compressed : ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFail() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Compression fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(float percent) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Compressing :"+percent, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }catch(Exception e){

        Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }



}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

}

Comment: You use Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT to get an uri. And then you take uri.getPath(). But then you do not have a path to a classic file. Better use a file picker who delivers a real path to a file. If you want to continue with ACTION_GET_CONTENT then copy the contents of the obtained uri first to a classic file and use the path to the file. In short: make a copy first.

Comment: Please edit your post so the code is in one block.

Comment: sorry about the code being in separate blocks, i have edited it hope , i will try your answers.

Comment: i have tried to make a file from the uri i have and then refer to its path ,if this what you meant , i did this using { File file = new File(videoUri.getPath)} and then use the created file path in the constructor but it didnt work too, would you please show me a better way to do it , i want to continue using Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT.

Comment: That is completely wrong as new File() does not create a file at all. And that path is useless. I suggest you google for a normal copy file function first. Then we can adapt it using a content scheme.

Comment: i believe that i need to go back to the documents take my time and learn more about the file class and internal and external storage things , so i understand more what i am doing., but i appreciate the help really anyway ,thanks :) :)